# characteristic subgroup and minimal normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

G is a solvable group, |G| = $ap^m$, where $p\nmid a$, G has a normal abelian Sylow $p$-subgroup H, and H is the unique minimal normal subgroup in G.

K is a normal subgroup of G, |K|=$p^m q^n$, Q is a Sylow q-subgroup of K.

So Z(K) $\lhd$ G. If Z(K) $\neq$ $1$, then it contains a minimal
subgroup which must be a minimal normal subgroup of G. Hence H $\leqslant$ Z(K), for H is the unique minimal normal subgroup of G. But since K = HQ, it
follows that Q char K, hence Q $\lhd$ G, so H $\leqslant$ Q.

I have spent almost two days thinking on this.

Q1: how the minimal subgroup of Z(K) is a minimal normal of G. I tried to prove that it is characteristic but failed.

Q2: Can Q char K be proved by arguing that no automorphism of G can map any element of Q outside Q because of the order of the element?

Q3: from Q $\lhd$ G, we can get H $\leqslant$ Q? Uniqueness of H implies containment? I'm not sure.

Thank you!

Comment: Since $H\leqslant Z(K)$ you have that both $H$ and $Q$ are subgroups of the normalizer of $Q$ on $K$. Thus, that normalizer must be equal $K$, so that $Q\unlhd K$, that is, $Q$ is a normal Sylow $q$-subgroup of $K$ and so It is characteristic on $K$.

Comment: $Z(K)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then It contais a minimal normal subgroup of $G$, which must be equal $H$ by minimality.

Comment: Same argument to $H\leqslant Q$.

Comment: thank you for your input! so a normal subgroup of G must contain a minimal normal subgroup of G, I suppose?

Comment: Yes, because $G$ is finite.

Comment: clear now! thx very much!

Comment: You're welcome.